# Generating SOAP response in Camel

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have created a web service flow in Camel (with cxf) that exposes a simple web service. However, it needs to be integrated with an external system that take in part of SOAP request as XML (**EXT.OUT** quque) and responds back via XML (**EXT.IN** queue) as shown in the figure below.

I do not have control over the behaviour of the external system, but I want to ensure the SOAP response is generated (i.e. from XML) based on the response I get from EXT.IN queue.

[image]

So far my flow looks as follows:

```
from("cxf:bean:myCamelWSEndpoint") // #1
  .transform().simple("${in.body[0]}") // #2 get Body object
  .process(soapToXmlProcessorRef) // #3 Processor that sets the exchange.out.body to some xml snippet
  .to(ExchangePattern.InOut, "activemq:queue:EXT.OUT") // #4 sends XML to EXT.OUT queue
  .process(xmlToSoapProcessorRef) // #5 Processor that generates SOAP response object from incoming XML snippet
```

I've tested the rest of the logic of my flow by creating a mock EXT.OUT queue that simply generates the XML and returns it.

I would like to know how do I specify it to wait for a response that get sent to EXT.IN queue between steps #4 and #5 above?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The route will continue processing your exchange in step #5 if you either receive the response or a timeout occurs (20 seconds is the default). So as far as I understand it already does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pollEnrich("activemq:queue:EXT.IN")`.

Simplified test routes:

```
from("activemq:queue:EXT.OUT")
    .log("Received message from EXT.OUT and sent it to EXT.IN: ${body}")
    .setBody(constant("I was on the moon!"))
    .to("activemq:queue:EXT.IN");

from("direct:start")
    .log("Send message to EXT.OUT")
    .to("activemq:queue:EXT.OUT") // sends XML to EXT.OUT queue
    .log("Wait until message from EXT.IN is received and enrich")
    .pollEnrich("activemq:queue:EXT.IN")
    .log("Finally: ${body}");
```

Starting the route:

```
final ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBody("direct:start", "Hello, World!");
```

The output should be as follows:

```
[                          main] route2 INFO  Send message to EXT.OUT
[                          main] route2 INFO  Wait until message from EXT.IN is received and enrich
[read #0 - JmsConsumer[EXT.OUT]] route1 INFO  Received message from EXT.OUT and sent it to EXT.IN: Hello, World!
[                          main] route2 INFO  Finally: I was on the moon!
```